# Google Drive Android Api reset Play Services Authorization

Tags: google-drive-android-api

When debugging a GDAA app, I need to re-test a "brand new account" situation. I.e. getting the dialog that asks user to allow the Drive access:

> "[YourApp] would like to: View and manage Google drive files that you
>   have opened or created by this app"

Is there a re-set method that would get me back to ground zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reset this via the Drive "manage apps" page on the web.  Disconnect the app from your drive.

Comment: I was just about to burst into a flaming attack, since I've done just that with no result (yesterday). ... and suddenly I realized I did it on a different account that I'm running my test on. It may be  a sign that I should not work Sunday till late night. My apology to "fbrozovic". Both your answers are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the 'Google Settings' app on your device, in the 'Connected apps' section you should be able to select and disconnect your app. At least for other kinds of permissions (e.g. contacts), allowed apps show up there.

**Edit:** The same can be done via the web [here](https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions).

Comment: There's nothing called 'Google Settings' or 'Connected apps' on Nexus 4, Kitkat 4.4.2

Comment: That's strange; that app was introduced in an update of the 'Google Play services' over a year ago. Are you running the newest ones? On my Samsung Galaxy Note 3 with KitKat 4.4.2, I currently have Google Play services version 4.4.52. **Edit:** [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms) is the Play Store URL for the package.

Comment: I found it. Sorry for the confusion. It is an app. I was looking through my phone system settings. Thanks.

Comment: Glad we resolved our misunderstanding. But ultimately, the answer is incorrect, since it does not help me with my problem.

Comment: So your app doesn't show up in the list of connected apps? This [Google help page](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3466521?hl=en) also suggests that you should be able to manage all app permissions there.

Comment: please help on this disconnected apps issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24011801/after-disconnecting-app-google-drive-android-api-still-returns-successful-result